# bcryptjs compare function returns false when passwords contain numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, bcrypt

I have used bcryptjs to hash my passwords and the registration of the user takes place fine.
But when I try to login, the bcrypt.compare function returns a *false* promise if the passwords contain numbers or other characters. 
Everything works fine if the password is just letters. 
I have searched everywhere but could not find a solution for this error? 
Here are my files :

users.js (MODEL)

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    products: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
        ref: "Product"
    }],
    username: String
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(5,function(err,salt){
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password,salt,function(err,hash){
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(isMatch);
      callback(null, isMatch);
    });
  }
  module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
  }
```

app.js

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({username:username}, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!user) {
                return done(null,false, {message: 'Unknown user'});
            }
            User.comparePassword(password,user.password,function(err, isMatch){
                if(err) {
                    console.log("ERR1");
                    return done(err);
                }
                if(isMatch) {
                    console.log("MATCH");
                    return done(null,user);
                } else {
                    console.log("NOT VALID");
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
                }
            });
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null,user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
    User.getUserById(id, function(err,user){
        done(err,user);
    })
})
```

users.js (ROUTE)

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', function (error, user, info){
    if(error) {
        console.error(error);
            console.log('Failed login:');
    }
    if (user === false) {
        console.log("user not found");
    } else {
        // handle successful login ...
        console.log("logged in");
    }
}), function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.user);
});

router.post("/signup", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;
    if(password == password2) {
        var newUser = new User ({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.username
        });

        User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            console.log(user);
            res.send(user).end();   
        });
    } else {
        res.status(500).send("{errors: \"Passwords don't match\"}").end()
    }
});
```

Whenever I enter a password that contains numbers, I get

```
false
NOT VALID
user not found
```

I'm sorry if I have done or not done something extremely simple. This is my first time using bcryptjs.
All answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the users.js file at the `comparePassword` function inside the `compare` method of bcrypt you are throwing the error instead of passing it to the callback. Maybe if you make this change:

```
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
      console.log(isMatch);
      callback(err, isMatch);
    });
}
```

You will see what kind of error it's generated by the case when you introduce numbers in your passwords.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I made the changes and the **err** is still null. That is, there is no error and isMatch is still false.